# Automapping complex objects in a profile

Tags: c#, automapper

Given the following class structure...

```
public class Response
{
     public Data SomeData { get; set; }
     public Data2 SomeMoreData { get; set; } 
}

public class Data
{
     public String DataString { get; set; }
}

public class Data2
{
     public String DataString2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyData
{
     public String DataString { get; set; }
     public String DataString2 { get; set; }
}
```

And given the following (very simplified) AutoMapper profile class

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
     public MyProfile()
     {
          CreateMap<Data, MyData>();

          CreateMap<Data2, MyData>();
     }
}
```

How can I create another mapping in the profile so that when I'm actually executing the mapping I can use this...

```
Response currentResponse = GetResponse();
var result = mapper.Map<MyData>(currentResponse);
```

I have some classes with a lot of properties, the majority of which can be mapped without having to fiddle with the properties very much, but I want some simple code calls for testing and maintainability.

I've seen a lot of answers with the static Mapper class, but I'm not finding much when it comes to profiles.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like the following:

```
 MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(expression => expression.AddProfile(new MyProfile()));
 IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

You now have an instance of `IMapper` that can be injected by your choice of DI as a singleton.